# prediction for multinomial logit model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, prediction

How can i have a prediction for each of the dependent variables in the multinomial logit model? when I use predict function, I have a prediction for each of the rows of data, I need a prediction for each of the dependent alternatives in R.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new dataframe and set the variables as you need. For example, if there are 3 variables (x, y and z). You will create something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble( x = 0:10, y = 0, z = 0)
df2 <- tibble( x = 0, y = 0:10, z = 0)
df3 <- tibble( x = 0, y = 0, z = 0:10)

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

And then use it on predict function.

```
df_predict <- predict(model, df)
```

Comment: thank you for replying,  i actually need to do sensitivity analysis, I want for example do an analysis for 50% more income and 50% less income to see the results for the car dependency? now i want to have a table with the prediction for 0,1,2 or more car when the income is not changing and when the income is changing for 50%and -50%

Comment: how should i set the tibbles?